# Replace img bbcode with optional width and height using regex?

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I really don't get the right solution.

My standard img replace code is:

```
preg_replace('~\[img](.*?)\[/img\]~s','<img src="$1" />',$text);
```

Of course it works. But im trying to replace the bbcode if width and height is set. **But thats optional, so it should work also if only 1 dimension is set or nothing.**

The bbcode looks like: [img=12x12]link of the image[/img]

So the bbcode should look like:

```
 preg_replace('~\[img=(.*?)x(.*?)\](.*?)\[/img\]~s','<img width="$1" height="$2" src="$3" />',$text);
```

I guess I got it wrong. Anybidy knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
preg_replace('~\[img=?(\d+)?x?(\d+)?\](.*?)\[/img\]~s','<img width="$1" height="$2" src="$3" />',$text);
```

The way you coded it, it wouldn't match all 3 cases you wanted: `[img]`, `[img=NN]`, and `[img=NNxNN]`. It would only match in the case both dimensions were provided.

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp should definitely work. I would have used `\d+` though which makes sure the value exists and are of numeric type:

```
~\[img=(\d+)x(\d+)\](.*?)\[/img\]~s
```

What error are you getting with your code, or rather, what string are you expecting to match but you don't?

Comment: @user3904923 did this help any or do you want more help?

Comment: Actually it does. Thanks for your help. I didnt say it was wrong, it just didnt managed it like it should. But The other regex seems to work. :)